# AWS Fargate Task Schedule Expression Rule First Run Time

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-fargate

I've written a CloudFormation template to deploy a container via Fargate task every X number of hours. The frequency is decided by the stack user with a parameter and then scheduled using a scheduled expression rule.

The question I have is when does the very first invocation of the scheduled expression rule take place? Say I have the rule run the container every 6 hours. Should the rule immediately run the task and then run it again every 6 hours, or does it first wait 6 hours and then run the task for the first time?

I haven't been able to pin down why, but if I upload the same exact CloudFormation template to AWS, ~50% of the time the task executes immediately and ~50% of the time it waits X hours to do its first run. I thought it could be a weird race condition in my template so I set the scheduled expression rule to depend on everything else, making it run last and ensuring everything it needs would already be built, but it made no difference.

The [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) state `A rate expression starts when you create the scheduled event rule, and then runs on its defined schedule.`, but I'm not sure if that means it starts running or starts waiting at creation time. I'm hoping someone can help me figure out AWS's behavior.

Relevant parts of my CloudFormation template for reference:

```
"Parameters": {
    "ExecutionFrequency": {
        "AllowedValues": [2, 4, 6,],
        "Description": "The number of hours to wait in between runs.",
        "Type": "Number"
    }
},
"Resources": {
    "ScheduleRule": {
        "Properties": {
            "Description": "Schedules the Fargate task to run every X hours.",
            "Name": "myRule"
            "ScheduleExpression": {
                "Fn::Join": ["", ["rate(", {"Ref": "ExecutionFrequency"}, " hours)"]]
            },
            "State": "ENABLED",
            "Targets": [
                {
                    "Arn": "myClusterArn",
                    "EcsParameters": {
                        "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
                        "NetworkConfiguration": {
                            "AwsVpcConfiguration": {
                                "AssignPublicIp": "ENABLED",
                                "SecurityGroups": "mySecurityGroup",
                                "Subnets": ["mySubnet"]
                            }
                        },
                        "PlatformVersion": "LATEST",
                        "TaskCount": 1,
                        "TaskDefinitionArn": "myTaskDef"
                    },
                    "Id": "myTaskDef",
                    "RoleArn": "myRoleArn"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Type": "AWS::Events::Rule"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not definitive but I would have thought the rule would run immediately then again after x hours.

You should check Cloudtrail for Start Task or Run Task Api operations when your container does not run to see if there has been an attempt to run it that actually failed on the first time but succeeded the second - potentially if you are also creating the IAM role used by Cloudwatch to run the task.

You havent shown all of the template, but assuming the role used by Cloudwatch to run the task is also in the template, try creating that role outside the template and referencing it from within your template and see if that gives you consistent behaviour.

There may be a race condition. The role is always created in the us-east-1 region (under the hood ) despite the region you are deploying the template to. I have suspected race conditions before where the only thing I could think of was that an asynchronous call to create the role had completed, but the role itself was not ready, and this was despite using DependsOn attributes in the template - though I could of course be completely wrong.